# How can a VBox guest access NFS-shares?

Tags: virtualization, nfs, virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox guest VM, which is configured to operate behind VirtualBox' "NAT". I can access various network shares via [smbnetfs](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smbnetfs/), but attempts to access the same via NFS fail with the error message stating: `Client credential too weak`.

Presumably, the error is due to VirtualBox' NAT-implementation using a port-number above 1024 for the outgoing connection -- even though the `mount_nfs` program inside the guest uses a lower port (because I run it as the guest's `root`).

Is there a way to change VBox' settings to do this properly? I'm pretty sure it *can* -- because it runs (or should run) as the Windows "administrator" already...

*Update*: yes, if I change the network configuration from NAT to one of the direct options, the error goes away, which proves, that VirtualBox process has the necessary privileges -- just chooses not to use them.

Is there a way to make it keep the outgoing port, when doing the NAT?

Comment: Can you put it on a "Bridged" vbox net connection vs NAT ? That would put it on the same subnet as the host machine, with its own IP, etc. and direct access would be no problem.

Comment: No. A new host appearing on the network trips alarms -- even when it is a harmless VM of a legitimate user -- and so the network admins don't like it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access NFS shares run:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "name of your VM" --nataliasmode1 sameports
```

Comment: Note: this answer is easy to misread, it's a number 1 rather than a letter l at the end of nataliasmode1.